# How to test a char array for letters only (including whitespaces)?

Tags: c++, string

I'm making a function for basic information input. This function will be later used to get information and store on disk.
I've made two checks. is_alpha and is_digit.
The issue with is_alpha is, it return "0" if it detects white space(which is not what i want). I'm taking input for "Name" and obviously it can contain spaces!
Can you please tell me how to make a method which checks my char array if it is a name? (Alphabets and white spaces)

```
class Bankaccount
{
protected:
int id;
char name[50];
char address[100];
char phone_no[50];
static int count;

public:
Bankaccount()
{

    count++;
    id = count;
}



bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
bool is_alpha(const std::string& s)
{
std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
{cin.ignore(); return !s.empty() && it == s.end();}
}

void basics ()
    {system("cls");
    cout << "Enter Name (Letters only): " << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name,50);


    {cout << "Enter Address: " << endl;
            cin.ignore();
cin.getline(address,100);
    cout << "Enter Phone Number (Digits only): " << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(phone_no,50);
    //CHECK FOR DIGITS ONLY
    bool temp=0;
    temp=is_number(phone_no);
    {while(temp!=1)
        {cout << "ReEnter Phone Number: " << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(phone_no,50);
        temp=is_number(phone_no);
        }
    }//while ends

    }



    {cout << "ReEnter Name: " << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(phone_no,50);

    cout << "Enter Address: " << endl;
            cin.ignore();
cin.getline(address,100);
    cout << "Enter Phone Number (Digits only): " << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(phone_no,50);
    //CHECK FOR DIGITS ONLY
    bool temp;
    temp=is_number(phone_no);
    if (temp==1)
    {}
    else {cout << "ReEnter Phone Number: " << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(phone_no,50);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You could use either std::isspace or std::isblank along with std::isalpha. What is the problem?

Comment: How do i use isspace and isalpha together?
I'm a beginner. Please help!

Comment: Names can also contain hyphens and apostrophes. Better make a is_validnamecharacter() function.

Comment: @Qurat_D  For example if ( std::isalpha( c ) || std::isblank( c ) ) std::cout << "Valid character\n";

Comment: 'isblank' takes int :/ and my input it char array

Comment: Qurat, all is*() functions take ints. That's no problem, the char value fits in an int and will be automatically "promoted". I would combine Vlad's example with stefaanv's advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you know that c++ has in-built STL function for isalpha(char).

so what you have to do is to implement a check for space or alphabets (for a name).

Let me help you, please refer to the code below:

```
bool isValidName(string word) {
    for(int i=0;i<(int)word.length();i++) {
        if ((word[i] != ' ') && (!isalpha(word[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please take note that i am assuming you declare the following in your header:

```
using namespace std;
```

if not then you have to write std:: in front of any std related things. e.g. `std::string`.

Just pass the name to the parameter of the function above and you are good to go.

Hope it helps!